# .net C# Dynanic IE not presenting to front on Visible

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

```
 dynamic ie =Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application"));

ie.AddressBar = false;
ie.MenuBar = false;
ie.ToolBar = false;

ie.Visible = true;
ie.Navigate("www.google.com");
```

I used the code provided there but cant get it to come to front when opening.

Is there an easy way to make it always on-top or just bring to front...

Preferably the first always on top.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Make it Always on top use the SetWindowPos from user32 API:

```
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);//-2 would make it not topmost
const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
                                           int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

then in your code:

```
dynamic ie = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application"));

ie.AddressBar = false;
ie.MenuBar = false;
ie.ToolBar = false;
ie.Visible = true;
ie.Navigate2("www.google.com");
SetWindowPos((IntPtr)ie.HWND, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 1280, 700, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SetForegroundWindow API:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
```

Then use it like this:

```
SetForegroundWindow(ie.Hwnd);
```

Comment: This answer works awesome as well... To bad I cant tag 2 answers as correct.

Thanks for your input